# Can I / How Do I Branch a Specific Directory

Tags: svn

I want to create a branch of a specific directory inside my code base.  I don't want to create a whole new copy of the repository.

Can I create a branch of a single directory (with all it's subfolders) without copying the whole repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you branch via `svn cp`, you're not duplicating anything. Instead, all you're doing is creating a *pointer* to a branch point.

You can make a branch of your directory (and all subdirectories), but I highly recommend you create a branch of the entire project:

```
$ svn cp --parents $REPO/trunk/project  $REPO/branches/4.2/project
```

This doesn't take up any more room in the repository and will execute instantly. Before I'm branching the whole project, I can checkout the project from the branch, and be able to build my project on the branch. I could just branch the particular directory:

```
$ svn cp --parents $REPO/trunk/project/subdir $REPO/branches/4.2/subdir
```

But that makes it impossible to build your branch since it doesn't contain the whole project.

The advantage with using `svn cp` is that it allows Subversion to do merges since Subversion knows where the branch came from:

```
$ svn co $REPO/trunk/project
$ cd project/subdir
$ svn merge $REPO/branches/4.2/project/subdir
```

This will all of the changes you've made on your branch back to the trunk.

***NOTE***: I am assuming you are using a Subversion 1.8 client. Otherwise, you get into the whole *reintegrate* vs. *merge* issue.